# is there a way to save what's printed on the display with gnu screen?

Tags: ssh, terminal, gnu-screen

I like to save everything I do on the command line, for example when I upgrade something and want to read back how the upgrade went etc..

Usually with Mac OSX and Terminal you can scroll back as much as you want, and save with Cmd-S. But when I'm on SSH using gnu screen, then I can't scroll back directly from terminal.

How can I save to disk everything that happens in a screen session? Maybe by default (every session automatically creates a file to disk...)

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a logging feature in `screen`. Start it when you start `screen` by doing `screen -L` (or from within `screen`). Or, also from within `screen`, you could press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd>.

If you want to have logging on as the default, add the following line to your `~/.screenrc` file:

```
deflog on
```

You may want to set the filename using something like:

```
logfile /tmp/screenlog.%n
```

Comment: One should maybe not store it on /tmp, as it usually gets cleaned on reboot (e.g. because of power failure).

Comment: @maxelost: That's something to consider. It was just an example, though. The point was to include an absolute directory since the default behavior is to create the log file in the current directory. Also, `screen` sessions (even detached ones) do not survive reboot.

Answer (score 5):

Option 1:
Look into the script command. "man script"

"Script makes a typescript of everything printed on your terminal.  It is
 useful for students who need a hardcopy record of an interactive session as
 proof of an assignment, as the typescript file can be printed out later
 with lpr"

Basically type "script" (no quotes) - do your work, and type exit once to end the session.

Option 2: Use screen's "hardcopy" mode. 'Crtl-a' then 'h' This will save the current session to a file.

note: GNU Screen does have the ability to scroll. Use 'crtl-]' (right square bracket) to enter copy mode, then 'ctrl-b' and 'ctrl-f' to move p and down a page at a time.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the 'log' operation, usually bound to `Ctrl-a H`.  This opens a new file called screenlog.*N* where *N* is the window number.   If the file exists, then output is appended to the file.  All output in that window is logged to the screenlog.*N* file until you deactivate by pressing `Ctrl-a H` again.  You can also get this functionality with `Ctrl-a :log`.  You can change the name using the `logfile {filename}` command.  The file gets placed in the directory in which screen was first started, but that can be changed with the logfile command or with `chdir [{directory}]`.

Note that this is not the same as hardcopy or the scroll buffer.  This is the same functionality as the script(1) program, but tied to a single window and without calling a new program.

If you want to save the entire  contents of the scroll buffer, use `Ctrl-a ] g <space> G <space> Ctrl-a :writebuf`  This saves the scroll buffer to the file /tmp/screen-exchange.  if you want to save only a portion, then change the 'g' and 'G' to other movement keys.